# Calling a C function from Fortran where the C function name was originally passed in from C

Tags: c++, c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

For reasons that are not relevant, I need to pass a C/C++ function name into a Fortran subroutine, which, in turn, calls that C function. What I have found is that I can succesfully pass the function name into the Fortran subroutine. In that subroutine I can call the correct C function. However, the arguments of the C function get broken on this call (when called directly from C it works fine). I have used [ISO C Binding](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Interoperability-with-C.html) to try and get this to work, to no avail.

Here is a MWE:

#### fortranRoutine.h:

```
extern "C" {
    void fortranRoutine_(void(int status));
};
```

---

#### calledfromFortran.h:

```
void calledfromFortran(int status);
```

---

#### main.cpp:

```
#include "fortranRoutine.h"
#include "calledfromFortran.h" 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    calledfromFortran(12);
    fortranRoutine_(calledfromFortran);
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### fortranRoutine.f90:

```
subroutine fortranRoutine(calledfromFortran)

    use iso_c_binding

    implicit none

    interface
        subroutine calledfromFortran(status) bind (c)
            use iso_c_binding
            integer(kind = c_int), intent(in) :: status
        end subroutine calledfromFortran
    end interface

    integer(kind = c_int) :: one

    one = 2
    call calledfromFortran(one)
    return

end subroutine fortranRoutine
```

---

#### calledfromFortran.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdlib.h"

using namespace std;

void calledfromFortran(int status) {
    cout << "In calledfromFortran:" << endl;
    cout << " status: " << status << endl;
}
```

---

### Current results

Running this currently gives:

```
In calledfromFortran:
 status: 12
In calledfromFortran:
 status: -1641758848
```

The first call to `calledfromFortran` from `main` works correctly, but when it's called from `fortranRoutine` the value is broken. Note, each time it's run that latter value changes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: its been a while but I believe fortran passes all arguments by reference. Shouldn't it be calledfromFortran(int * status);?

Comment: @frankc Um, yup. You're totally right. Want to write it as an answer?

Comment: nah, that's ok. I see now the other guy suggested forcing it to pass by value, which is just as good as accounting for the default pass by referene behavior.  Note that if you pass strings, there are other things you need to do, like handle the hidden length parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When passing scalar values between Fortran and C, you have basically two options:

- You pass them by reference: On the C-side you have to make sure, that you use pointers to those scalars.
- You pass them by value: On the Fortran side you have to make sure that you use the `VALUE` attribute, as already suggested by other posts.

As for the `intent(in)` attribute, it can stay there, as it does not affect, whether the variable is passed by value or reference. In Fortran, arguments are always passed by reference unless you specify the `VALUE` attribute. The attribute `intent(in)` only tells the compiler to prevent a usage of that dummy argument in the routine, which would change its value.

Additional note on the naming: You should specify your Fortran routine `fortranRoutine` also with `bind(c)`. This way you can specify its name as seen from C, even if it is inside a module:

```
module my_interface
  use iso_c_binding

contains

  subroutine fortranRoutine(calledFromFortran) bind(c, name='fortranroutine')
  ...
  end subroutine fortranRoutine

end module my_interface
```

This way you can be sure, the name of the function to be called from C is `fortranroutine`, independent of the convention of the compiler to append underscores, prepend module names or convert names to lower case. Consequently, you would have a a header file in C, which should work *compiler independently*:

```
extern "C" {
  void fortranroutine(void(int status));
};
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out both methods of doing it. Will `bind(c, name=...)` break it if it's called from Fortran instead of C?

Comment: If you call it from Fortran, you just call it by its *Fortran* name (`fortranRoutine` or `fortranroutine` as Fortran names are in contrast to C-names case insensitive). Of couse, you will have to import the module my_interface in that scope.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the interface definition to read

```
interface
    subroutine calledfromFortran(status) bind (c)
        use iso_c_binding
        integer(kind = c_int), VALUE :: status
    end subroutine calledfromFortran
end interface
```

I am not sure what `intent(in)` was, but that bit of the code does not look right. Apart for that, the rest looks (at first pass) reasonable and right.

*Note. The ISO C bindings were only added in the 2003 releae of the FORTRAN language, so if you are using an older version it might be worth checking the compiler documentation for details. Some compilers allow ISO C bindings, but maybe called slightly differently than that I have displayed above.*

---

Edit. Having looked into the `intent` keyword, you might try using `intent(in)` in conjunction with the following type declaration, that follows the `interface` definition

```
integer (c_int), parameter :: one = 2
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fortran/Fortran_procedures_and_functions#Intent) about the intent. That needs to stay, actually (legacy code issues). The ISO C binding syntax is correct, I believe.

Comment: The `value` attribute seems to work! Now I just need to make sure it doesn't break other features...

Comment: I am intriuged. I have done this a few times, and used example code which always adopter the `VALUE` keyword. What compiler are you using? What version of the language? I am not sure why intent(in) is not working in this case; see my edit.

Comment: It's legacy code, so parts of it are written in everything from F77 to F2003. It also generates a library used by others, so I'm trying to minimize the number of changes required to link to a C code.

Comment: Also, if I understand correctly, the `VALUE` attribute essentially passes by value rather than address. Is there a way to modify the C portion of the code to expect an address rather than a value?

Comment: That is my undestanding from what I have read of `intent`. The VALUE, definately passes by value. However, I must caution you that I have not used the `intent` keyword, and whether it passes a reference/pointer; you will have to check the docs. All the best...