# How to use fortran module subroutine in c

Tags: c, fortran, icc, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to use a fortran module subroutine in c and cannot get through, here is a simplified version of my problem:

I have one fortran module that contains a subroutine, and the second subroutine uses the module.

```
!md.f90
module myadd
implicit none
contains

subroutine add1(a) bind(c)
implicit none
integer a
a=a+1

end subroutine add1
end module myadd


!sb.f90
subroutine sq(a) bind(c)
use myadd
implicit none
integer a
call add1(a)
a=a*a
end subroutine sq
```

Now I want to call the `sb` function in c:

```
//main.cpp
extern "C"{ void sb(int * a); }
int main(){
  int a=2;
  sb(&a);
}
```

how should I link them together?

I tried something like

```
ifort -c md.f90 sb.f90
icc sb.o main.cpp
```

but it gives error

> sb.o: In function `sq': sb.f90:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to`
>   add1' /tmp/icc40D9n7.o: In function `main': main.cpp:(.text+0x2e):
>   undefined reference to`sb'

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Here's a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557439/how-to-call-a-fortran90-function-included-in-a-module-in-c-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(void){
  int a=2;
  sb(&a);
  return 0;
}
```

and

```
module myadd
use iso_c_binding
implicit none
contains

subroutine add1(a) bind(c)
implicit none
integer (c_int),intent (inout) :: a
a=a+1

end subroutine add1
end module myadd


!sb.f90
subroutine sq(a) bind(c, name="sb")
use iso_c_binding
use myadd
implicit none
integer (c_int), intent(inout) :: a
call add1(a)
a=a*a
end subroutine sq
```

with

```
gcc -c main.c
gfortran-debug fort_subs.f90 main.o
```

It is easier to link with the Fortran compiler because it brings in the Fortran libraries.

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot! Do you know how to do the same using intel compilers? I always get error with intel : main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
for_main.o:/export/users/nbtester/efi2linux_nightly/branch-13_0/20120801_000000/libdev/frtl/src/libfor/for_main.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/compilers/Intel/composer_xe_2013.0.079/compiler/lib/intel64/for_main.o: In function `main':
/export/users/nbtester/efi2linux_nightly/branch-13_0/20120801_000000/libdev/frtl/src/libfor/for_main.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `MAIN__'

Comment: @xslittlegrass, if you use `ifort` to link Fortran code with a C/C++ `main()` function, you should give it the `-nofor-main` option, otherwise the compiler links the `for_main.o` object file, which contains a `main` function, which in turn calls the main Fortran program (usually named `MAIN` under the hood).

Comment: @HristoIliev It works! Thanks. Do you what is the compiler flag for icc to ask icc to bring in the fortran library?

Comment: @xslittlegrass, I'm not aware of such option. It's probably best to use `ifort` to link mixed-language applications.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your link error is twofold:

- you omitted the object file for the source file that holds the module from the final command line (md.o).
- you've called `sq` in the fortran `sb` in the C++ code.

Fix those and you'll be right to go.