# Calling a subroutine in a module from C

Tags: c, module, fortran

I would like to know how I can get a C program to call a Fortran 90 subroutine contained withing a Fortran 90 module.

[This question deals with a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557439/how-to-call-a-fortran90-function-included-in-a-module-in-c-code?lq=1), and I'm trying to implement the solution, but I'm still having issues.

Here are toy examples of the `testC.c` file, which contains the main function, and the module file `testF.f90`, which contains the Fortran 90 subroutine.

testC.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern void __testF_MOD_fortfunc(int *,float *);

int main() {
   int ii=5;
   float ff=5.5;

   __testF_MOD_fortfunc(&ii, &ff);

   return 0;
}
```

testF.f90

```
module testF

contains

subroutine fortfunc(ii,ff)
    implicit none

    integer ii
    real*4  ff

    write(6,100) ii, ff
    100 format('ii=',i2,' ff=',f6.3)

    return
end subroutine fortfunc

end module testF
```

To compile, I am using the following lines

```
gcc -c testC.c
gfortran -o testF.f90
gcc -o test testF.o testC.o -lgfortran
```

I get the error message

```
testC.o: In function `main':
testC.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `__testF_MOD_fortfunc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I've updated my question to be more specific about the issue. Namely, it fails at compile, and says "undefined reference to __testF_MOD_fortfunc

Comment: The order in which files are listed matters to the linker.  It may solve your problem to swap testC.o and testF.o in your link command.

Comment: Tried swapping testC.o and testF.o. No luck unfortunately.

Comment: FYI: You don't need to specify function declaration as "extern". AFAIK it's only usable for variables.

Comment: Please use the the generic tag [tag:fortran]. Otherwise you are referring to a specific standard that is more than 25 years old (hint: the latest released standard is Fortran 2008, Fortran 2015 is in the works). As an added benefit, more users are following the generic tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `objdump -t testF.o` to read out the function name from an object directly. This reveals the following line:

```
0000000000000000 g     F .text  00000000000000b4 __testf_MOD_fortfunc
```

That's your function name. You can see that it is `testf` in lowercase. 
Using this in the C code should solve your problem.

However, these naming conventions are compiler dependent. You should really take a look into the `ISO_C_binding` module and the improved C interoperability of modern Fortran.