# Calling a Fortran subroutine from C# at the console

Tags: c#, fortran, interop

I want to call a Fortran subroutine from C# using commands entered at the console.
I have been trying for two days now, reading many web pages, and following much advice, but with no success.

Here is a typical example of my many failed attempts.

Using a text editor (Notepad) I create this file called "fdll.f90"

```
 module fdll
implicit none
 contains

 subroutine testFDLL(char)
 character(12) :: char
    write(6,*)" Hello FORTRAN : let us do something ...",char
 return
 end
 end module
```

At the MS-DOS console (CMD.EXE), I type the following command and press "Enter" :

```
 C:\Compilers\fortran\mingw32\bin\gfortran.exe -shared -o fdll.dll fdll.f90
```

Two new files appear, named "fdll.dll" and "fdll.mod".

Using the Monodevelop C# text editor, I create the following C# source file called "DLLImport.cs"

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class DLLImport
{       
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunFortranDLL ();
    }
    
public static void RunFortranDLL()
    {
        FortranLib.testFDLL("Please work!");
    }
}

public static class FortranLib
{
    private const string dllName = "fdll.dll";
    [DllImport(dllName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    public static extern void testFDLL(string Plea);
}
```

At the console, I enter the following command :

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe /t:exe /out:go.exe DLLImport.cs
```

A new file appears called "go.exe". I type "go".

The result is a popup window telling me "go.exe has stopped working". It gives me the option to close the program. At the MS-DOS console, the following message has appeared:

```
 Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
 at Fortran.Lib.testFDLL(String Plea)
 at DLLImport.Main(String[] args)
```

What have I done wrong? How can I make this work?

I am using a 64-bit SONY laptop running Windows 8.1. I am using the latest verion of gfortran (i686-w64-mingw32).

UPDATE: I modified the Fortran source code to allow for ISO_C_BINDING (following Pierre's suggestion). The new version is:

```
 module fdll
 contains
 subroutine testFDLL(char) bind(C)
     USE ISO_C_BINDING
     character (C_CHAR) :: char(20)
    write(6,*)" Hello FORTRAN : let us do something ..."
 return
 end subroutine
 end module
```

I also modified the C# source code to make it send the character string into Fortran as an array (as explained here: http://www.luckingtechnotes.com/calling-fortran-dll-from-csharp/). The new C# code is:

```
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public static class DLLImport
 {       
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    RunFortranDLL ();
}

public static void RunFortranDLL()
{
    FortranLib.testFDLL(ToCharacterArrayFortran("Please work!",20));
}

public static char[] ToCharacterArrayFortran(this string source, int length)
{
    var chars = new char[length];
    int sourceLength = source.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (i < sourceLength)
            chars[i] = source[i];
        else
            chars[i] = ' '; // Important that these are blank for Fortran compatibility.
    }

    return chars;
   }
 }

 public static class FortranLib
 {
     private const string dllName = "fdll.dll";
     [DllImport(dllName, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

public static extern void testFDLL(char[] Plea);
 }
```

I made no changes to the command line arguments running the compilers ; neither compile, gfortan nor csc, complained about any of these changes.

RESULT: when I run the program (enter "go") the same error message appears.

Can somebody please explain what is wrong, or missing, with what I have done. Is it really this hard getting C# to send a character string into a Fortran subroutine?

Comment: Have you read about the `iso_c_binding` features of Fortran?

Comment: Thanks. If you can show me where that goes into my source code, or my commands, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `iso_c_binding` is a set of features, including specifiers that arrange for a C style calling convention (ABI) between Fortran and C (not C# you have to consider the code as C). This is a well known topic, so it is your task to *at least* try it and post your adapted code here before anyone would provide further help.

Comment: Sure. I will try it. In all of my researches on this topic (interoperability of C# and FORTRAN) there has been no mention of  "iso_c_binding". But I will look into it.

Comment: Fortran does not have a direct "C#" capability. You need to consider it as a C interface.

Comment: Not sure whether it will help by try adding a -fPIC to the gfortran compile line

Answer (score 1):

I just try to show how to interface this FORTRAN code with C, this does not fully answer your question, but if you know how to interface C (pretend the FORTRAN as C) with C#, it should help.

```
!fortran code, named as x.f90
module fdll
    implicit none
contains

subroutine testFDLL(str, n) bind(c, name='testFDLL_as_C')
    use ISO_C_BINDING
    integer(c_int), value :: n
    character(kind=c_char), intent(in) :: str(n)
    write(6,*)" Hello FORTRAN : let us do something ...",str
    return
end
end module
```

And the C code calling FORTRAN subroutine.

```
//c code explicitly link. named as y.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    void testFDLL_as_C(char *str, int n);
    char str[] = "Hello from C";
    testFDLL_as_C(str, strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

You can pretend your FORTRAN subroutine as a C function and call from C# as usually ways. The C test code gives:

```
  Hello FORTRAN : let us do something ...Hello from C
```

You can also implicitly link with the dynamic library as the following (note, ignore all error check and close of resources for shorter example).

```
//implicit link. named as z.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    void (*func_from_so_f90)(char *str, int n);
    char str[] = "Hello from C, again, using dynamic dlopen()";
    void *handle = dlopen("./libxf90.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    func_from_so_f90 = dlsym(handle, "testFDLL_as_C");
    func_from_so_f90(str, strlen(str));
    return 0;
}
```

The command to compile them (on linux) are

```
gfortran -o libxf90.so -shared -fPIC x.f90
gcc -o yout y.c ./libxf90.so
gcc -o zout z.c -ldl
```

The output of the 2nd program is like:

```
  Hello FORTRAN : let us do something ...Hello from C, again, using dynamic dlopen()
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my FORTRAN code to be identical to yours, but the error message remains. Your C code is interesting. I cannot see how to modify my C# code to mirror it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to identify it's FORTRAN problem, C# problem, interface problem or run-time environment problem. I assume you know how to call C dll library from C#, because I don't know C#. You can try use C as intermediate, call C dll from C# first to eliminate possible issues that are not FORTRAN related. My example is just the FORTRAN related part. Try to isolate problems first.

Comment: How did you compile your FORTRAN code? Can you please give me the exact syntax of your console command line.

Comment: I just compile it as gfortran -c x.f90 to test the code. It may not be helpful because you want to compile it into dynamic link library. As I said, the example just shows FORTRAIN and C Interoperability, your exact issue may be on other part of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

The C# definition is incorrect.  It should be

```
public static extern void __MOD_fdll_testFDLL(byte[] Plea);
```

see [how to call a Fortran90 function included in a module in c++ code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557439/how-to-call-a-fortran90-function-included-in-a-module-in-c-code/15586601#15586601)

You can use nm, if you have it, or the dependency walker to find out what the exported symbols are.

Note that C# char is 2 bytes, Fortran char is 1 byte and the way arrays are stored is different in both Fortran and C#.

If this is just an interoperability test, try working with just integers first and make sure that works.  Then move on to a single character (byte) and then on to arrays.  Don't go on to arrays in your first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

i686-w64-mingw32 means that you need to compile C# with x86 (not AnyCPU)